# trying to loop through a belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

Trying to use a [`prawn-rails` gem](https://github.com/Whoops/prawn-rails).

I know that that I'm doing the `posty` method all wrong because I'm not looping through it correctly, am I? Same goes for what I have in `posty.pdf.prawn`

**User Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name :string
#  last_name  :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchkick word_start: [:user]
    has_many :posts
    validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

**Post Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string
#  body       :string
#  date       :date
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, :body, presence: true
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

**routes**

```
  resources :users do 
    resources :posts
  end
```

According to directions of prawn-rails, I'm supposed to create the method in the controller, create a view of it with the same name as the method, and fill in that view.

**Method in Posts Controller**

```
  def posty 
    @user = User.all
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**posty.pdf.prawn**

```
prawn_document do |pdf|

    pdf.font_size 25 
    pdf.text 'List of Posts by User', :style => :bold

  @post.each do |p|  
    pdf.font_size 16
    pdf.text p.title
  end
end
```

This is the error that comes up: (screenshot)

[image]

**EDIT**

**Routes**

```
    users_test GET    /users/test(.:format)                    users#test
   posts_posty GET    /posts/posty(.:format)                   posts#posty
          root GET    /                                        users#index
        search GET    /search(.:format)                        search#search
    user_posts GET    /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
               POST   /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
               PATCH  /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
               PUT    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
               DELETE /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
         users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
               PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
```

**EDIT 2**

**Posts Controller**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string
#  body       :string
#  date       :date
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def posty 
    @posts = User.find(params[:user_id]).posts
  end 

  def new 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    render :edit
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save 
      redirect_to user_path(@post.user)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to user_path(@post.user)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
      redirect_to users_path
    end


  private 
  def set_user
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def set_post
     @post = @user.find(params[:id])
  end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :date)
    end
end
```

**Users Controller**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name :string
#  last_name  :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.page(params[:page]).per(10)
    query = params[:query]
    query = '*' if query.blank?
    @users = User.search(query, page: params[:page])
  end

  def test 
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save 
      flash[:notice] = "User successfully added!"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render :edit
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path
  end

  private 

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
    end

end
```

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT AGAIN**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you assosciation `post belongs_to user`, so it should be one user who has many posts, so the method should be,

```
<%= link_to "Download PDF", posts_posty_path(:format=>:pdf, :user_id => @user.id) %>
```

Send the user_id from the above link which we will use in posts method,

```
  def posty 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
    if @user.present?
     @posts = @user.posts
    end
  end
```

Change `@post` to `@posts`

Also add a condition in posty.pdf.prawn file as,

```
prawn_document do |pdf|

    pdf.font_size 25 
    pdf.text 'List of Posts by User', :style => :bold
  if @posts.present?
    @posts.each do |p|  
      pdf.font_size 16
      pdf.text p.title
    end
  end
end
```

This will work for you.

Comment: good news is that it finally went to `posty.pdf.prawn` and generated an error there instead of the `posty` method in the posts controller. I've included the screenshot at bottom of my question.

Comment: send `@posts` instead of `@post` from posty controller

Comment: I added a condition in prawn file in my answer pleae check once.

Comment: I added it to the `posty.pdf.prawn`. Good news is that the pdf file finally comes up. The bad news is that besides the title of `List of Posts by User`, it's otherwise blank!

Comment: Yes thats what the condition is appled for, that User does not have the posts, so the error came, assign some posts to that user and your issue is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116645/discussion-between-sravan-and-user27307254534534534543675765).

Comment: actually, the user does have posts. Please look at the latest screenshot above. All the users have posts generated via seeds file. As you can see from the url, it's the first user. And they do have posts.

Answer (score 1):

Well one problem I see is that in your posty method `@user.posts.find(params[:id])` expects there to be a single user in the `@user` instance variable, but in the previous line you assigned **all** the users to `@user`.  Hence you are getting that error message.

Then in your posty.pdf.prawn file `@post` should be `@posts` for the `each` iterator to work.  So in your controller you should have `@posts = @user.posts` instead

Comment: just changed it to `@posts = @user.posts`, but same error still comes up. My problem is that I don't understand how to loop through posts that belongs to users. How do I do that?

Comment: You're probably still getting that error because you haven't properly assigned @user a single user.

Comment: So, `@user` should be `User.find(params[:user_id])`?

Comment: ugh, now it comes up with this error: `Couldn't find User with 'id'=`

Answer (score 0):

Good catch by Ren. The `Post belongs_to :user` and `User has_many :posts` relationships work for a single user. Not an array of users (which is what `User.all` would return.)

You'll need to grab a single user. For example, via `@user = current_user` (if using Devise).

Answer (score 0):

By your given nested resource, you have an user_id that points to your user resource. Use `rake routes` to have an insight on what params are given by convention in your resources routes. In your posts#index action therefore you have to fetch the user, then query the posts like `@posts = User.find(params[:user_id]).posts`. As you'll need this particular user in every of your nested resource, you may want to write a before action like...

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # ... the bacon

  private

  def set_user
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def set_post
     @post = @user.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Added routes to question. Also ... so, you're suggesting to have this: `@posts = User.find(params[:user_id]).posts` in my posty method? and to have `set_user` and `set_post`?

Comment: What route did you try? Something like `/users/1/posts`? Did you then ensure there is a user with id=1?

Comment: just added both posts and users controllers above.

Comment: route? you mean for `posty` method? have added routes above as well, but this is what i've written `get "posts/posty"`

Comment: So it's that route you bother, not your controller action? I'm still unsure what you are trying to achieve... anyway the route `posts/posty` has no information about the user (user_id), you need to add a specific route information there. As you are not using an index action in your PostsController I'd suggest to just rename index like `resources :photos, path_names: { index: 'posty' }` then use `rake routes` and see hopefully what I expect you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: apologies for not being clear for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to generate the posts of the users in a pdf. As written in the post above, I did custom method in posts controller,ie, `posty`, wrote the method in 'posty.pdf.prawn`. These two areas are where I'm going wrong because I don't know how to associate posts to the users as you can tell by my `posty` method, and I'm not writing the method in the `posty.pdf.prawn` correctly either which should loop through the posts of the users, and print the titles of the posts.

Comment: Nothing to apologize for. With `@posts = User.find(params[:user_id]).posts` you get all posts of the user specified by user_id but you have to ensure user_id is part of your route (see `rake routes`). You can add this also as plain GET param ?user_id=1 to test the results. If you want all the posts, not only of one user, you simply query the Post model like `@posts = Post.all`.